# Como faço para chamar outra tela em java, não estou conseguindo

Tags: java

Segue código da Classe TelaPrincipal

```
package telas;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import java.awt.Window.Type;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class TelaPrincipal extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TelaPrincipal frame = new TelaPrincipal();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public TelaPrincipal() {
    setTitle("Cadastro Geral v 1.0");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);       
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JButton btnCadastrar = new JButton("CADASTRAR");
    btnCadastrar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            new TelaCadastro().setVisible(true);
        }

    });
    btnCadastrar.setBounds(91, 135, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnCadastrar);
}
}
```

Classe TelaCadastro

```
package telas;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class TelaCadastro extends JInternalFrame {

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                TelaCadastro frame = new TelaCadastro();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public TelaCadastro() {
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);

}

}
```

Comment: Mesmo assim não está chamando a tela de cadastro.

Comment: Ocorre algum erro?

Comment: Não, simplesmente a outra tela não aparece

Answer (score 2):

Em seu código a classe 'TelaCadastro' está estendendo de um 'JInternalFrame', para poder usar este tipo de frame você deve adicioná-lo em um JDesktopPane, este é o problema do seu código, a principio.

Recomendo que de uma olhada neste artigo para aprender como usar, mesmo estando em inglês é de fácil entendimento.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Answer (score 1):

Para que seja mostrado a outra tela, se você já tiver criado ela, basta você implementar um `Actionlistener` de um botão, incluir o evento no botão, dentro do evento `action` e, você coloca para chamar a outra janela assim:

```
Classe janela = new classe()
janela.show;
```